# Prepend multiline text to file with ansible

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml

I want to add this to the top of a file:

```
#
# Ansible managed
#
```

I tried [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html), which works but is not idempotent - it adds another one on every ansible run.

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /some/file
    regexp: "^#\n# Ansible managed\n#\n"
    line: "#\n# Ansible managed\n#\n"
    insertbefore: BOF
```

I tried [`blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html), which adds the block in the middle of the file (no idea why), and adds another one thereafter on every ansible run.

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
    path: /some/file
    marker: ""
    marker_begin: ""
    marker_end: ""
    insertbefore: "^#\n# Ansible managed\n#\n"
    block: |
      #
      # Ansible managed
      #
```

I tried [`replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html), which badly mangles the file (adds the block before every line).

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /some/file
    regexp: "^(?:#\n# Ansible managed\n#\n)?(.*)$"
    replace: '#\n# Ansible managed\n#\n\1'
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the module [ansible.posix.patch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/patch_module.html#ansible-posix-patch-module-apply-patch-files-using-the-gnu-patch-tool). For example, given the file on the remote host

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/test.txt
line1
line2
line3
```

Create the patch file

```bash
shell> cat files/a.patch 
0a1,3
> #
> # Ansible managed
> #
```

---

Example how to create a patch

```bash
shell> cat a
line1
line2
line3
```

```bash
shell> cat b
#
# Ansible managed
#
line1
line2
line3
```

```bash
shell> diff a b
0a1,3
> #
> # Ansible managed
> #
```

---

The play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - ansible.posix.patch:
        src: a.patch
        dest: /tmp/test.txt
```

will patch the file

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l test_11

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.posix.patch] **********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/test.txt
#
# Ansible managed
#
line1
line2
line3
```

The *patch* task is idempotent.